# onscreenclick() for RawTurtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm writing my code with RawTurtle and I found out that on turtle, the function onscreenclick() is used to let the user click on the window. However, RawTurtle doesn't have the the same thing as far as I known.
Is there anyway that I can let the user click on the canvas created with RawTurtle?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway that I can let the user click on the canvas created
>   with RawTurtle?

Yes. Rather than passing the `Canvas` object to `RawTurtle`, instead wrap the `Canvas` object in a `TurtleScreen` object and pass that to `RawTurtle`:

```
screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
turtle = RawTurtle(screen)
```

This give you most of turtle's screen-related methods (e.g. `bgcolor()`), just apply them to the `screen` instance:

```
screen.onclick(myEventHandler)
```

(We don't use the longer form `onscreenclick()` here as that's used to disambiguate from turtle's `onclick()` when we use turtle *standalone*, not *embedded* in tkinter.)